# Issue with arguments in php function array_intersect

Tags: php, array-intersect

can you help me with this question :

```
$array = array();

foreach ($request['priceDifPeriod'] as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = range($request['priceDifFrom'][$key], $request['priceDifTo'][$key]);
}

return array_intersect(?????);
```

Where ????? - I need put `$array[0], $array[1]` and others (`return array_intersect($array[0], $array[1], ...... , $array[n]);`)

How i can do this, thank you.

Comment: Which two array you want to intersect?

Comment: Try this `return array_intersect(implode(", ", array_values($array)));`

Comment: I try it, ErrorException: Array to string conversion

Comment: Please [edit] your question to form a [mcve].  We don't have sample data or your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

its working `return call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$array);`